# Export image collection Google Earth Engine to Google Cloud Bucket Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, modis, cloud-gis

I have an image collection within GEE's Python API that I want to clip and write to my google cloud bucket. I am working on a Google Cloud VM and have mounted my bucket "gee-bucket22" with gcsfuse. I have successfully written images from my ee.batch export in the past, but for an unknown reason, my task is not executing. The task does not report an error and does not successfully write images. The status of the task is 'state': 'READY' when calling task.status(). Is there an additional step to execute tasks I'm missing?

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
AOI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.647,-33.669,115.690,-33.685])

imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').filterDate('2017-01- 01', '2018-10-01').filterBounds(AOI).select('EVI')
collectionList = imageCollection.toList(imageCollection.size())

out_image = ee.Image(collectionList.get(1))#export first image
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(
       image=out_image,
       bucket='gee-bucket22',
       fileNamePrefix='exampleExport')
task.start()
print(task.status())
```

I'm sure my bucket is mounted because after running

```
gcsfuse gee-bucket22 ~/mnt/bucket-location
```

I receive a response "bucket successfully mounted".